# Schlage B62 Deadbolt Removal

Tags: lock, deadbolt

Need help removing a Schlage B62 deadbolt from a front door. It’s a double sided one, and has no faceplate or screws for removal. Deadbolt is also stuck and won’t lock or unlock when key is in.

Comment: Pictures of both sides.  The screws are hidden behind something.  Might be a little pin hole somewhere on the inside.  If you do not want to take the time looking, I find a sledge hammer is a good remover for most things.

Comment: Some of the Schlage products have a pair of raised bumps. They are covers over the screws. remove them by prying them up with a small flat blade screwdriver.

Comment: Have you looked at Schlage's website for service information?

Comment: If there aren’t screw caps on the interior, try twisting the covers.

Comment: Looks like they either have a couple of little caps covering the screws, or the entire center of the face pops off. https://hardwarehut.com/images/moreimages/deadbolts/schlage/b62-exterior-interior-609-big.jpg  Got pics of both sides of your locks?

Comment: Thanks for the responses. There are 2 little caps that we popped off but there are just little holes and no screws.

Comment: Look deeper in the holes.  There would not be caps there for no reason.